# Magento 2 Tier Price using API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

it looks like is not possible to use "Tier Price" when creating an order with API in Magento 2.x

Can you confirm that?
Is there a solution to create an order and get the price based on tier price group price ?

Dave

Comment: As i know , you can set the price directly in the JSON body, Magento will not check the prices, I suggested to send all data in the order body, Prices/Totals etc...

Answer (score 0):

When loading the tier pricing you need to know the `website_id`.  If you have only one store view, this is normally `0`.

To load tier pricing, you need to use the `catalogTierPriceStorageV1` endpoint (see [the swagger documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#!/catalogTierPriceStorageV1)).

Be warned that the update didn't work for me (it just added more prices, not updtaing the existing ones), so when my prices change, I "get" all the magento prices, "delete" them, then load all my new ones (luckily, you can re-use the "get" JSON data that is returned and plug it into the "delete" with very simple "{prices{" at the start and "}" at the end).